# PageRequestManagerServerErrorException, typing xml inside a textArea control on C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, postback

I'm trying to have XML text (Actually `<?` breaks it already) inside a textarea to show it to the user, not to edit. Looks like on the postback as i press the save button to save some other control values, i get something like on the browser console:

```
Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: 
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Unknown error at processing... Response: 500
```

The code never reaches the load of the page for the postback, so i don't think it's not an error on my code.

I already tried to add

> validateRequest="false"

in the `<%@ Page` directive but didn't work out.

Is there any way to show the user some XML text without having the postback blow away?

Comment: Did you try encoding the <? value before post back ? Any update panel has been used ?  Try below link :
http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it

Comment: Yes but then the text gest shown as the encoded like `&lt;?xml version=&quot;`... etc. About the link: There are no directives about Filters, Modules. Also there is no Server.Transfer or Response. Anyways it doesnt gets into my code, breaks doing the postback request